# Why does it give an error related to its setup when installing a library written in github?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

FastONN is a Python based open-source GPU implementation for Operational Neural Networks.
[fastonn](https://github.com/junaidmalik09/fastonn)
after clone the repository and run the following command from inside the directory:

```
!pip install .
I received following error:

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Processing /content/drive/MyDrive/Github/DM-Count/fastonn
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─\> See above for output.
```

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Could you help me solve this problem?

I searched the errors but it was mostly about pip and !pip install --upgrade pip and !pip install --upgrade setuptools didn't solve my problem.

Comment: 1. Dont use "!" in front of pip. If you use that, it will search your command line history and executes that.. While it might work, showing that as a command you run will not be helpful at all ..  2. Include a full error *like you did* on the github issue. 3. Bug is setup.py on row 22 - remove the `'python_version >= "3.4"',` and `pip install .`  should work

Comment: I use Colab, that's why I used "!". Thank you for your help. Yes, this solved the problem.